# Definition of function

Tags: notation, proof-writing, article-writing

When defining a function, mathematicians often write something like this:

> Let $f\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be the function given by $x\mapsto x^2$.

The purpose of this definition may be to assert something about this function, for example:

> Then $f$ neither injective nor surjective.

One can shorten this whole thing as follows:

> The function $f\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R:x\to x^2$ is neither injective nor surjective.

My question is whether $f\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R:x\to x^2$ is a correct notation. Also, I wonder if there are alternative notations. Maybe using the "$;$" instead of "$:$"?

Comment: "Function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ prescribed by $x\mapsto x^2$ is neither injective nor surjective" is my favorite here. Your notation doesn't look familiar to me.

Comment: It's not common to write it exactly as you have with the extra colon.  Particuarly you used $\rightarrow$ instead of $\mapsto$ for elements.  Most typically people stack the two as $\overset{\large f:\Bbb R\rightarrow\Bbb R}{\ \ \ \ \ \ \ x\mapsto x^2}$

Comment: You could also just say "the function on $\Bbb R$ given by $x\mapsto x^2$ is neither injective or surjective."  Nowhere do you use the name $f$ so there's no reason to give it a name.